# USB not working? Or something else?

Tags: usb

I recently bought a 32GB USB. And it seems that it's from a rejected stock: My USB detects fine in Windows, and even writes and reads files and folders.

But, I can't change the format from FAT32 to NTFS (or any other file system), nor can I change the partition table to GPT, nor can I change the size of the FAT32 partition. Well, it would've been okay if I only used Windows.

The thing is, it won't be detected in Mac at all. (rdisk2 doesn't show up)
And, in Ubuntu, only /dev/sdb shows up in the devices, but /dev/sdb1 (which is the FAT32 partition) doesn't show up.

Then I tried doing a hex read of /dev/sdb in Ubuntu (since it at least got detected). And the file is of 0 bytes (as shown in GHex, with root permission).
Then I also tried doing a dd of /dev/sdb and I got a really weird thing:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzNsvDx_ae6bWU94T0RhVjdxOG8/edit?usp=sharing

That's the attached output of dd, cut short to 1MB. I got "Invalid system disk. Disk I/O error. Replace the disk, and then press any key." in what looks like /dev/sdb (since it's "dd") (though it really isn't).

I'm stumped. The drive works well in Windows (well, as long as I use the FAT32 only.. I can't change the partition) and I can read and write files.

What's going on out here? Another way of asking that question: Why can it write in Windows if it's spoilt? The shopkeeper's making a lot of money selling rejected items this way (and demonstrating in front of customers that it can work, so that they can't come later and tell them that it doesn't work)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what brand USB you are using but my 64GB Patriot Supersonic Rage XT had a similar issue that had me pulling hair out for a few hours.

It wasn't until I realized that Patriot uses some custom formatting to increase their read and write speeds at such high volume. That information led me to this solution : [Supersonic Rage Write Protect Low Level Fix Tool](http://www.patriotmemory.com/support/getDriversp.jsp)

Not sure if this is at all helpful for your particular issue, but if you are using a Supersonic Rage XT this is what worked for me.

Comment: It's a supposedly Transcend 32GB flash drive, though I now feel that it's a fake... Trying now to find the actual capacity of the drive using H2testw...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I got a lead…

I tried finding the capacity of the USB drive using

```
$ df -hT /dev/sdb
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
```

and it shows that its capacity is only 2GB!~

So the shop was selling fake USBs (or at least the controller reports a fake capacity). And now they don't take opened packets back :-(

So I have to now look how to make it report its true capacity…